# How to source data from multiple directories(file-system) in gatsby using graphQL

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a directory like this

[image: Directory]

where I have **posts** folder which may contain numerous folders and then each video folder may contain some videos.
Now, I have created dynamic pages for the `video and video_2`  folder using [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/).
I have two pages now and what I want is to fetch the specific two videos of that directory only in my template page.
what should be my graphQL for this?

Referrence: (For specific content from .md files)

```
query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

This is bringing the specific slug-wise data onto the webpage. What should be the query for sourcing the contents from file-system?(I am using `gatsby-source-filesystem`).

Hope my question makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're saying is you have a set of directories that should each be turned into a single page. Each page should display the videos that are in the directory.

You could do the following in your `gatsby-node`; retrieve all files, group them by directory and create pages for each directory.

Note the regex in the query that selects for which files you're interested in.

The `createPage` call sends the file names videos of the page as context so you might not need to do any further GraphQL query in your page.

See also https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/

```
const path = require("path")

function getDirectoryOfFile(pathName) {
  const pathEls = pathName.split(path.sep)

  return pathEls[pathEls.length - 2]
}

function groupFilesByDirectory(files) {
  return files.reduce((directories, file) => {
    const directory = getDirectoryOfFile(file)

    directories[directory] = (directories[directory] || []).concat([file])

    return directories
  }, {})
}

exports.createPages = async function ({ actions, graphql }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      allFile(filter: { absolutePath: { regex: "/video/" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            name
            absolutePath
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const files = data.allFile.edges.map(edge => edge.node.absolutePath)
  const directories = groupFilesByDirectory(files)

  Object.entries(directories).forEach(([directory, videos]) => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: `/video/${directory}`,
      component: require.resolve(/* your page template here */),
      context: { videos },
    })
  })
}
```

I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: I didn't know the ```context``` thing. Thanks for the answer and the doc link. Also, on my template page, what links should I provide to the ```<video src="??">```. Can you please tell me about the location of the dynamically created pages so that I can navigate it to my **{pageContext.slug}/video/video_2** folder. That would be a lot of help. @ehrencrona

Comment: To get a URL of the video files, check out https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/#querying-for-a-file-in-graphql-using-gatsby-source-filesystem

Comment: Thanks. @ehrencrona